# Reseting window position and size to default values

Tags: window

I somehow managed to change the size of the gedit window. Every time I open gedit, it is in the new size. I wonder if there is a way to return gedit to its default size, or whether anyone knows what the default size is. My screen res is 1920x1080.

[image: Gedit with funky size]

Comment: Does this (http://superuser.com/questions/664621/how-to-set-the-default-dimension-of-an-application-window) answer your question?

Comment: What's the "default size" according to you?

Comment: Open gedit, size the window to the desired size, then quit gedit. The next time that you start gedit, it'll remember the previous size.